# reference counting in ios with xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

There are so many questions on ARC & Reference Counting.
I am unable to understand difference between ARC concept & reference counting technique.I have created an application in ios4 .In ios4 there is no ARC concept so programmer has to take care of memory when releasing objects using reference counting.If programmer forget to release objects when created an application in ios4 if same application is run in ios5 what happens to unreleased objects?

Answer (score 1):

It will behave exactly the same as on iOS4 - it will leak. ARC is just a compiler feature that inserts retain/release/autorelease calls for you during compilation.

You can read about ARC concept here: [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226)

Answer (score 0):

With ARC, the compiler automatically inserts retain, release and autorelease in the program. However, ARC works only for objective-C objects. A good tutorial for ARC can be found here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1